# "Show Item With No Data" function is not working after making relationship between two table. How to Fix This?

Tags: powerbi

Power BI Desktop - I have two tables with Unique value.
Table one contains - Target for Each region.
e.g. APAC - 50, NA - 100, Europe - 200
Table two contains - Sales achievement for each region.
e.g. NA - 70, Europe - 90

Now Problem is - APAC region is not listed in 2nd Table. i created a matrix table and showing both table value in one table through relationship but after making the relationship, APAC region is not showing in third table list because its not there in 2nd table.

So please suggest how can i fix this?

I tried with "Show Items with No data" but it is also not working.

I want the unique list of regions from table 1 & 2 in 3rd table irrespective of value assigned to them or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a third table from unique region-values with DAX?
Something like this:

```
UniquesTable = DISTINCT(UNION(VALUES(Table1[Region]),VALUES(Table2[Region])))
```

You should connect Table1 and Table2 to UniquesTable in the Relationships-tab so that calculations with targets and achievements work as expected

Comment: Thanks Gigga, With this approach my issue is resolved.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad I was able to help!